# how to use anafanafo in a react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I am trying to use anafanafo to compute the text width used in an SVG component in my React app. My React app is created using TypeScript.

```
import anafanafo from "anafanafo"
const width=anafanafo(message, "11px Verdana")
```

I got following two errors:
(1)
Could not find a declaration file for module 'anafanafo'. '.../node_modules/anafanafo/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/anafanafo` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'anafanafo';`

I created a file anafanafo.d.ts at the current dir, does not seem working.

(2) ERROR in /.../node_modules/char-width-table-consumer/src/consumer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/.../node_modules/char-width-table-consumer/src'
No type errors found

Does anyone know how to fix the two errors?

Comment: You can write a simple routine to compute a text width

Comment: Yep. That is what I did eventually.